# java code for drawing huffman tree for encoding a sentence

Tags: huffman-code

I am able to huffman encode and decode the sentence but how do I draw the huffman tree for the same? please help with java code.

also after having constructed the tree, we should traverse the tree and create a dictionary of codewords

Comment: "I am able to huffman encode and decode the sentence" - good! So *how* does [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) work? This information is quite vital in being able to create an implementation, as claimed.